# installation Android SDk

Tags: android

I have installed the Android SDK Tools software.when i go to install the platform SDKs and their related tools the alert with the title "Refresh Sources" apper with the content: Found EDk 1.1 by Sony Ericsson Mobile Communication AB,Android API 10
"Failed to fetch URL http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml/addon.xml, reason: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml/addon.xml" 
help me plz right now cs i'm so tired to the installation of SDK android.thx

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out all the api's causing problem, they are not important anyway.